# Execution time of function

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

At the algorithm SELECT, there is the following step:

```
If $i=k$, then return $x$. Otherwise, use SELECT recursively to find the $i$th
smallest element on the low side if $i<k$, or the $i-k$ th smallest element on
the high side if $i>k$.
```

How could we find the cost of this step?

Comment: did you have a look at 'Analysis of Algorithms' on Coursera?

Comment: No, I have the book Introduction to algorithms by Cormen.. @Alex

Comment: In the Coursera courses (2 different actually) both algorithms are explained quite well

Comment: @Alex Can I find these courses online?

Comment: https://class.coursera.org/aofa-004/lecture

Comment: https://class.coursera.org/algo-007/lecture

Comment: [Quicksort complexity when all the elements are same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126586/quicksort-complexity-when-all-the-elements-are-same) and [algorithm complexity of quicksort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488453/algorithm-complexity-of-quicksort) might be good places to start.